# Logging request and response payloads in Hapi.js using Good

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am using Hapi.js to implement RESTful API for my mobile application. I have integrated Good for logging requests, errors, and other events. It works very well for me. However it is not clear how to log request and response payloads (JSON objects).

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is in the works. Look at https://github.com/hapijs/good/issues/175

Comment: That's true, Per. I have logged that issue, and it looks like the good folks at Good have kindly addressed it already. Can't wait till it's available in the next release (2.3.0)

Answer (score 4):

This logs what you need:

```
server.on('response', function (request) {
    console.log(request.info.remoteAddress + ': ' + request.method.toUpperCase() + ' ' + request.url.path + ' --> ' + request.response.statusCode);
    console.log('Request payload:', request.payload);
    console.log('Response payload:', request.response.source);
});
```

I haven't used `Good`, but I guess that connecting this to `Good` shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but it's worth putting here that you can now optionally capture request and response payloads with [good](https://www.npmjs.com/package/good):

> [requestPayload] - determines if the request payload will be available to reporter objects. Defaults to false
>
> [responsePayload] - determines if the response payload will be available to reporter objects. Defaults to false

For example:

```
var options = {
    responsePayload: true,
    reporters: [{
        reporter: require('good-console'),
        events: { log: '*', response: '*' }
    }]
};
```

Something to be careful of is that you will more than likely now be storing username and passwords in plain text in your log files. You should consider using the `filter` option when logging response and request payloads:

> [filter] - an object with the following keys:
>
> - key - the key of the data property to change
> - value - a string that can be one of the following:
>
>   - "censor" - replace the text with "X"s
>   - "remove" - deletes the value
>       a valid regular express string. Only supports a single group. Ex: "(\d{4})$" will replace the last four digits with "X"s. Take extra care when creating this string. You will need to make sure that the resultant RegExp object is what you need.

Comment: One thing to note is that it's not possible to use the console for request payload. Because the dev doesn't think it's useful lol. https://github.com/hapijs/good-console/issues/36 . So you'll need to use the log for that.